# How can I get python subprocess stdout and stderr to show up in Visual Studio's output window?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I switched to Python Tools for Visual Studio (VS2012) and I am trying to get my project up and running.  I'm having a problem with the stdout of subprocesses not showing up in the Visual Studio output window.  I've created some example code to illustrate the problem.

test_console.py

```
import os
import subprocess
print 'printed from the main process'
command = 'python '  + os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'test_console_sub.py')
subprocess.call(command)
```

test_console_sub.py

```
print 'printed from a subprocess'
```

The python console that shows up when executing test_console.py correctly shows the output from both files.

[image]

The output window is missing the subprocess print statement

[image]

Here are some of the relevant settings

[image]

How can I get the subprocess print statement to show up in the Visual Studio output window?  Ideally, the output window would look exactly like the python console window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround (seeing the answer of AnojiRox) you could catch stdout and stderr from the subprocess and then print it from the main process, but you need to use Popen and its [`communicate` method](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) due to the deadlock problem stated in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

```
import os
import subprocess

print 'printed from the main process'
command = ['python', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test_console_sub.py')]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

Comment: wow. I wasted twelve hours of my short life googling this... and you can do it in 7 lines of code..

Answer (score -1):

You can't.
I've searched for this before, and found nothing. correct me if i'm wrong.

Try using a text editor and python console instead.